.a файлы, для чего нужны
Что такое .a файлы, для чего используются

Расширение файла ".a" обычно указывает на архив библиотеки (library archive). В основном оно используется в unix-подобных операционных системах.
Например, если у вас есть файл libexample.a, это вероятно означает, что это статическая библиотека под названием "example".
